# What is a C++ atomic variable?

Tags: c++, synchronization, std

Here is the documentation for std::atomic: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Reading other questions what I've gathered is it generates some sort of special machine instructions (i.e. lock add) and that as a result you don't have to use a mutex around the variable.

What I want to know is how it works and what are the limitations to using them?

Comment: Any answer you get is going to be really long. A good start is to study up on what lock-free means. From there you can start to read the C++ standard starting with 29 Atomic operations library [atomics], and there's a lot to digest.

Comment: it does more than generate special machine instructions. It also prevents load/store reordering. The link to the videos in the answer below really should be followed - you'll be amazed at what you learn. You'll need 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you.  I will watch the videos.  I didn't realize it was so complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic really could fill a book. Likely you won't get any clear answers in this format.

Check out Herb Sutters videos, these are really the clearest discussions I've seen on the topic:

https://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/

See the links for "Part 1" and "Part 2".